# React useEffect cleanup function in StrictMode

Tags: reactjs

I have a chatbot component that renders some messages in chat history and also on the user's new chat input, it calls service and rerenders the component with the new response. My entire application is wrapped under `React.StrictMode` and because of the strict mode, `useEffect` is getting called twice which is setting the user input twice and subsequently calling the service twice. As I understand, it should call the cleanup function before running the next effect to keep the component pure. But I am not sure how a cleanup is implemented when `useEffect` is just updating the state. Please refer to the code below.

```
const Chatter = () => {
  const chatBotConfig = {
    messages: ["Need some help", "Sure"], //mesages in old chat history
    lastUserMessage: "what is programming",
  };

  return <ChatBot chatBotConfig={chatBotConfig} />;
};
```

```
const ChatBot = (props) => {
  const { chatBotConfig } = props;
  const [chatBotMessages, setChatBotMessages] = useState({
    messages: chatBotConfig.messages,
    lastUserMessage: chatBotConfig.lastUserMessage,
  });
  const callService = (lastUserMessage) => {
    //call service and then setChatBotMessages
    setChatBotMessages((prev) => ({
      messages: [...prev.messages, "New reponse from service"],
    }));
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Chat
        messages={chatBotMessages.messages}
        lastUserMessage={chatBotMessages.lastUserMessage}
        setChatBotMessages={setChatBotMessages}
        callService={callService}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
const Chat = (props) => {
  const { messages, lastUserMessage, setChatBotMessages, callService } = props;
  useEffect(() => {
    //problem as this effect is getting called twice
    if (lastUserMessage && lastUserMessage.trim()) {
      setChatBotMessages((prev) => {
        return { messages: [...prev.messages, lastUserMessage] };
      });
      callService(lastUserMessage);
    }
  }, []);
  return <div>{messages.map((message) => message + " ")}</div>;
};
```

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this `useEffect`?

Comment: The purpose of useEffect in <Chat> component is to trigger a service call. I have updated code for more clarity.

Comment: Not clear what the actual issue is. Do you see the messages duplicated in the rendered chat? If the service is called twice and state is set twice, but the rendered result looks correct, then your code is already pure, and you don't need a cleanup function.

Comment: @cjl750:
 As useEffect is getting called twice, the lastUserMessage is added twice into the messages array. So I think the solution to avoid this is to avoid callback in setChatBotMessages like below:
`code`
setChatBotMessages({ messages: [...messages, lastUserMessage]});
`code`
But I am not sure how to avoid the 2 times calling the service. I think I can use useRef having the initial value as false and in useEffect conditionally make it true on the first call of the service. is it right solution?

Comment: @Krishnath yes, that is definitely a valid option!